# Переключение между следующий/предыдущий popup в fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Есть карточка товара, при клике на которую появляется модальное окно, реализованное через fancybox. В этой карточке есть 2 кнопки внизу, следующий товар и предыдущий, при клике на которые появляется следующий\предыдущий popup соответственно.

Как можно такое реализовать?
Идея вроде понятная, закрываем все попапы, в fancebox для этого есть метод `close()`, и открываем следующий\предыдущий.
Но до ума довести не получилось. Может кто подскажет?

Comment: Ну добавьте на попап кнопки `вперед - назад`, и при переключении заменяйте содержимое попапа, новым. А вообще, желательно видеть код. что у вас уже получилось.